# Passing model between controller and multiple views

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor

I'm new to asp.net and am having a pretty basic issue (also don't have much experience in c# so I probably am misusing terminology). I have 2 views which are connected to the same model. In the first view the user input assigns a value to one of the model attributes - lets call it A1. In the second view, which relies on A1's value, the user input fills the rest of the model attributes, as seen in the example below.

Controller looks something like this:

```
    public ActionResult ClalledFromView1(MyModel model)
    {
        return View("View2", model);
    }

    public ActionResult CalledFromView2(MyModel model)
    {
        model.CheckAllAttributes();
        return View("View3");
    }
```

View1 looks something like this:

```html
<html>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("CalledFromView1", "ControllerName", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.A1)
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    }
</html>
```

View 2 looks something like this:

```html
<html>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("CalledFromView2", "ControllerName", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        @if (Model.A1 == "some value")
        {
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.A2)
        }
        else
        {
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.A3)
        }
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    }
</html>
```

What's happening is that by the time CalledFromView2 is called, A1 is empty but A2 is filled and is consistent with A1's original value. I want the same model being passed back and forth between controller and both views without clearing any attributes. TIA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to keep the A1 value passed,you can add a hidden input like this.

View2:

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("CalledFromView2", "ControllerName", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.A1, new { @hidden = "hidden" })
        @if (Model.A1 == "some value")
        {
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.A2)
        }
        else
        {
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.A3)
        }
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    }
```

Here is a demo:

Model:

```
public class ModelA
    {
        public string A1 { get; set; }
        public string A2 { get; set; }
        public string A3 { get; set; }


    }
```

Controller(Test3):

```
public IActionResult TestModelA()
        {
            return View();
        }
        public ActionResult CalledFromView1(ModelA model)
        {
            return View("View2", model);
        }

        public ActionResult CalledFromView2(ModelA model)
        {
            //model.CheckAllAttributes();
            return View("View3");
        }
```

TestModelA:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("CalledFromView1", "Test3", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.A1)
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
}
```

View2:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("CalledFromView2", "Test3", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.A1, new { @hidden = "hidden" })
    @if (Model.A1 == "some value")
    {
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.A2)
    }
    else
    {
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.A3)
    }
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>


}
```

result:
[image]

Comment: You mean your model.listOfEmptyObjs is a list have some empty objects?If so,you cannot bind textbox with a list.List need to be foreach and bind data.And you need to change name of the textbox..net core bind data with name attribute.And list need to be bind with name liking  `listOfEmptyObjs[index].property`.You'd better  to open a new issue,and add more details about it.